# Azure AD user data access?

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin, azure-active-directory

I have a Xamarin.Forms application which uses Azure AD B2C authentication. While I could make the signing in work, I still need to, somehow, fetch the user information (like username and other attributes stored in AAD) to display it in application. I couldn't find any proper documentation on what should be done in order to achieve that. Anyone else had similar issues or know what I should look for?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C directory user profile comes with a built-in set of attributes, such as given name, surname, city, postal code, and phone number. You can extend the user profile with your own application data without requiring an external data store. You can also use Microsoft Graph to get attributes from Azure AD B2C user profiles.

Please look into a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57675567/azure-b2c-how-to-retrieve-built-in-user-claims-attributes) that can help you with the issue.

For the supporting documentation please refer [B2C-user-profile-attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes).